# How to prevent clients from unobfuscating code from Ioncube?

Tags: php

I am going to encrypt that with ioncube when giving to a client side
and I will simply include to call the licensing system. But the problem is when I simply include the code

```
include "lic.php"
```

the user can directly remove the line to get the script worked. How can I write a script inside the lic.php which will make the script to prevent from running if the code i.e. is removed from the file? Note that I will include the line in all the php files in my script.

Comment: If the user can modify the source code, you can only make hir life harder, but you have no 100% way to stop hir from removing your licensing code.

Comment: It looks like the answer below is correct - would you accept it, Unix Man? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you distribute the *encoded* script, the users don't see the source code and cannot modify it. That's the idea of an encoded script.